# calculate the queue for orders based on creation and delivery date, by product group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, row

I have a Pandas dataframe containing records for a lot of orders, one recorde for each order. Each record has `order_id`, `category_id`, `created_at` and `picked_at`. I need to calculate queue length for each order at the time of it's creation. Which means for each record `current_order` I need to count the number of rows with following conditions:

- must have the same `category_id` as the `current_order`
- must be created before `created_at` of the `current_order`
- must be picked after `created_at` of the `current_order`

The dataframe is quite larg hence doing the calculation using a loop is too time consuming.
How can I do this faster?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited**

A sample of dataframe:

```
          id  category_id          created_at           picked_at
0  123228779        69558 2021-05-22 00:08:46 2021-05-22 00:22:45
1  123228972        69558 2021-05-22 00:12:39 2021-05-22 00:17:00
2  123229120         6725 2021-05-22 00:15:47 2021-05-22 00:42:50
3  123229210        41358 2021-05-22 00:17:44 2021-05-22 00:35:34
4  123229152         6725 2021-05-22 00:16:29 2021-05-22 01:05:43
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your dataframe, this would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Let me know if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602086/16343464) is what you want, otherwise please provide the expected output.

Comment: what is your expected output from it?

Comment: @AnuragDabas from what I understand, the purpose is to calculate how many orders (per group) are in queue at time of creation, when a new order arrives, counter increases, when an order is picked up, counter decreases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first start by reshaping the dataframe to have `created_at` and `picked_at` in the same column. Then we calculate the queue value.

```
df2 = (df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'category_id'],
               var_name='type',
               value_name='time')
         .sort_values(by=['category_id', 'time']) # not required to sort by "category_id",
                                                  # but done here for clarity
      )

df2['queue'] = (df2['type'].map({'created_at': 1, 'picked_at': -1})
                           .cumsum()
               )
```

```
>>> df2
          id  category_id        type                time  queue
2  123229120         6725  created_at 2021-05-22 00:15:47      1
4  123229152         6725  created_at 2021-05-22 00:16:29      2
7  123229120         6725   picked_at 2021-05-22 00:42:50      1
9  123229152         6725   picked_at 2021-05-22 01:05:43      0
3  123229210        41358  created_at 2021-05-22 00:17:44      1
8  123229210        41358   picked_at 2021-05-22 00:35:34      0
0  123228779        69558  created_at 2021-05-22 00:08:46      1
1  123228972        69558  created_at 2021-05-22 00:12:39      2
6  123228972        69558   picked_at 2021-05-22 00:17:00      1
5  123228779        69558   picked_at 2021-05-22 00:22:45      0
```

Finally, we reshape the queue to the original dataframe:

```
df['queue'] = (df2.pivot(columns=['type'],
                         values=['queue'])
                  .loc[:, ('queue', 'created_at')]
                  .dropna()
                  .astype(int)
              )
```

output:

```
          id  category_id          created_at           picked_at  queue
0  123228779        69558 2021-05-22 00:08:46 2021-05-22 00:22:45      1
1  123228972        69558 2021-05-22 00:12:39 2021-05-22 00:17:00      2
2  123229120         6725 2021-05-22 00:15:47 2021-05-22 00:42:50      1
3  123229210        41358 2021-05-22 00:17:44 2021-05-22 00:35:34      1
4  123229152         6725 2021-05-22 00:16:29 2021-05-22 01:05:43      2
```

NB. this gives us the queue, per `category_id`, after creation.