# Fast pandas indexing: select on multiple columns for each date in date_range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Given a large dataframe (> 5.000.000 rows), with two datetime columns and an ID column:

```
df.head()
                       ACQ                    START  ID
0  2020-10-19 09:00:04.000  2020-10-19 16:00:07.800   0
1  2020-10-19 12:00:00.000  2020-10-19 16:00:07.800   2
2  2020-10-20 09:00:14.400  2020-10-20 19:00:16.400   2
3  2020-10-20 14:02:30.400  2020-10-20 19:02:19.000   1
4  2020-10-21 09:04:10.200  2020-10-21 09:05:19.200   2
```

I need to get for each `ID` the number of rows that **start after** a date AND are **acquired before** it, for all the dates in a `pd.date_range` (with periods > 100).

This is what I came up with. It works, but it's slow (especially `df = df[df["START"] > d]`)

```py
ids = []
for d in datelist:
    df = df[df["START"] > d]
    ids.append(
        df[df["ACQ"] < d]
         .groupby("ID")
         .size()
    )
ids = pd.DataFrame(ids).fillna(0.0)
```

I also tried using `ACQ` and `START` as indices and slicing instead of boolean indexing, but it appeared to be slower.

Is there any way to improve this? I was not able to find anything in pandas that indexed a list/series at once.

Thanks

---

If you want to run this here's a toy example

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  {"ACQ": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-19 09:00:04.000"), "START": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-19 16:00:07.800"), "ID": 0},
  {"ACQ": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-19 12:00:00.000"), "START": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-19 16:00:07.800"), "ID": 2},
  {"ACQ": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-20 09:00:14.400"), "START": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-20 19:00:16.400"), "ID": 2},
  {"ACQ": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-20 14:02:30.400"), "START": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-20 19:02:19.000"), "ID": 1},
  {"ACQ": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-21 09:04:10.200"), "START": pd.to_datetime("2020-10-21 09:05:19.200"), "ID": 2}
])
start_date = pd.to_datetime("2020-10-19")
end_date = start_date + pd.Timedelta(days=2)
datelist = pd.date_range(
    start=start_date,
    end=end_date,
    periods=10
).tolist()
ids = []
for d in datelist:
    df = df[df["START"] > d]
    ids.append(
        df[df["ACQ"] < d]
         .groupby("ID")
         .size()
    )
ids = pd.DataFrame(ids).fillna(0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# START ≥ start_date           ACQ ≤ end_date
(df['START'].ge(start_date) & df['ACQ'].le(end_date)).groupby(df['ID']).sum()
```

*NB. use `gt` and `lt` for a strict comparison (after/before not including the date itself)*

output:

```
ID
0    1
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That would only work if I needed to compare only `start_date` and `end_date` though. The hard/slow part is to check for all the intermediate dates created by `pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)`

Comment: @gekrone then I might have misunderstood the question. Can you provide some explicit examples and detailed logic?

Comment: Sure, check my question for the code I wrote. In short, for each `d` in `pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, periods=N)` I want to get the number of rows, grouped by ID, that have `START > d & ACQ < d`. So basically what you answered, but for every date in a list/`pd.Series`

Comment: what is the point of checking all values in a defined range? If I ask you how many items in `range(20,100)` are above 30 and below 120, you won't check all of them one by one, but do 100-30 (min of maxes - max of mins), right?

Comment: No. I do not want to know how many dates in `pd.date_range` are between a start and an end. I want to know how many rows are in `df` such that `START > d & ACQ < d`, grouped bi `ID` and for each date `d` in the `pd.date_range`

Comment: Solved with an adaptation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601304/calculate-the-queue-for-orders-based-on-creation-and-delivery-date-by-product-g/68602086#68602086. Thanks, if you edit your answer I'll approve it